# How to pass NULL value to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#

I have Perl code to pass a parameter value to an Oracle stored procedure like below,

```perl
$func->bind_param(":testParam", undef);
```

Now I'm trying to call the same stored procedure from C#.

How can I pass `undef` in C#?

I already tried below the ideas below, but I am getting an empty result set,

```C#
objCmd.Parameters.Add("testParam", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = null;
objCmd.Parameters.Add("testParam", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = string.Empty;
objCmd.Parameters.Add("testParam", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: You should pass as `DBNull.Value` does it not work?

Comment: i tried this too, but no help

Comment: post your procedure definition once.